# How can you determine elements in a collection when Unit testing a void method?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a void method similar to this

```
public void handle(MyObject myObject) {
   Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>();
   mySet.addAll(myObject.getStuff();

   ...

   mySet.addAll(someOtherList);

   ...

   myService.doSomething(mySet);
}
```

I am using Mockito. I have mocked myService and I am verifying that myService.doSomething(mySet) gets called with any Set like this:

```
verify(myService).doSomething(any(Set.class));
```

But I want to verify the expected contents of the set. I tried something like this:

```
Set<String> expected = new HashSet<String>();
expected.add("item1");
expected.add("item2");
verify(myService).doSomething(expected);
```

This verified failed because due to "Argument(s) are different" as expected was [item1,item2] while actual was [item2,item1]. So the content is the same but not in the correct order.

How can I check that the contents are the same without changing the collection being used that maintains order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you've simplified your example too much? Two `Set` instances will be equal provided that they contain the same objects, regardless of order.

See my example test below, which passes.

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

  Foo foo = mock(Foo.class);

  Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
  set.add("a");
  set.add("b");

  foo.doSomething(set);

  Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>();
  set2.add("b");
  set2.add("a");

  verify(foo).doSomething(set2);
}

public interface Foo {
  void doSomething(Set<String> strings);
}
```

Comment: You were correct. It was not failing due to order. It was failing properly because the number of elements expected was different than the actual result.